# Android null pointer exception on ArrayList for ListView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a listview that shows the contents of an arraylist. I'm using a simple adaptor to make this possible like so.

```
public static ArrayList<String> homeScreenContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, NewContact.homeScreenContacts);
```

The second line is giving me a null pointer exception. I thought about it and I decided it was because the arrayList is empty. So I added the following line between the arraylist declaration and the arrayadaptor declaration...

```
NewContact.homeScreenContacts.add("A Contact");
```

This solved the problem and my code worked fine but Now the list view shows "A Contact" and I dont want it to. Is there anyway to get rid of the null pointer exception problem but still have the arraylist empty? Because I want to populate it with user made contacts, not hard-coded, random strings. Thank you.

EDIT: Sorry, The arraylist is located in another class called NewContact, also, I am very beginner Android Programmer I just started.

Comment: Why you use NewContact.homeScreenContacts ?

Comment: just get the data from the user into the list...?

Comment: Use homeScreenContacts and not NewContact.homeScreenContacts? Are they same?

Comment: @Hardy The arraylist declaration is in a class called NewContacts.

Comment: An empty List should not force the adapter to a NPE.

Comment: @Clay if you want to use arraylist from a different class pass the arryalist to the current class in which you use using intents retrieve the same and use it for arrayadapter.

Comment: How you adding values to NewContact.homeScreenContacts ?

Comment: @Hardy I just say homeScreenContacts is public static. And I just say NewContact.homeScreenContacts.add("hello").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution just don't initialize the `ListView` if there is no element in the `ArrayList` or the `ArrayList` is null.

```
if(NewContact.homeScreenContacts != null && NewContact.homeScreenContacts.size() > 0){
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, NewContact.homeScreenContacts);

   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Also you need to remember that if you you haven't initialize `Adapter` then dont initialize the `ListView` and before any operation on list view you should check is it null or not.

As you have said that you want to populate when user add some contact in the application then on add event only you need to populate or update the `ListAdapter`.

Hope this solution will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity 

    {
        private ListView lv;
        public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
              setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
             lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
             // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, you already have yours)
             ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
             your_array_list.add("foo");
             your_array_list.add("bar");
             // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
             ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
             new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
             lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what my code looks like now. The problem is, my list view now shows foo and bar and I dont want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
if(arrayList.isEmpty())
{

        listView.setAdapter(null);
}
else
{
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```